# iFrame in Unity for loading webpages

Tags: unity-game-engine

iFrame is very common in HTMLs, where we can easily upload an https link and load it in our server. Is there a similar way to achieve this in Unity? Not for WebGL, but for Windows/Android applications.

Such that we load the webpage on a canvas and then the mouse interactions will be active for the website as well. I am looking to especially load a 3D model from the webpage.

Comment: An IFrame ist just Website in a Website. You need a full-featured WebView to view the page and the 3D Content.